# How to validate random walk model

Tags: forecasting, arima, random-walk

I am studying ARIMA models and find it hard to validate the model in terms of "it's a good, useful model" and "I shouldn't use that model for prediction".

So at first I started with the easiest model, a random walk, where the model uses the mean value of the series.

Let's say I have the series:

```
data1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data2<-c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1)
data2<-c(10,-5,33,1,96,45,-978,3,15,8,9,32,12)
```

All three are random walks, but obviously the values of the first series `data1` are better to predict than for `data2` or `data3`.

My question is, how can I quantify this kind of reliability in a metric? (Ideally in a single metric from 1.0 for `data1` and ~0 for `data3`). Probably the variance is the metric, but how can I standardize it to tell if the predictions from the models will be "good" (1.0) or "bad" (0.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you may be misunderstanding what a random walk is. It is a process $x_t$ the value of which at time $t$ is equal to the initial value plus the cumulative sum of shocks at times $1,...t$, i.e.

$$x_t=x_0+\varepsilon_1+...+\varepsilon_t$$

where the $\varepsilon$'s are random shocks. It could also be expressed as the most recent value plus the most recent shock:

$$x_t=x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$

Your variables `data1` through `data3` do not seem to be realizations of a random walk process.

The forecast of value at time $t+1$ given the value at time $t$ equals to value at time $t$ in a random walk model:

$$\hat{x}_{t+1|t} = \mathbb{E}(x_{t+1}|x_t) = \mathbb{E}(x_t+\varepsilon_{t+1}|x_t) = \mathbb{E}(x_t|x_t)+\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_{t+1}|x_t) = x_t+0 = x_t$$

This is because the shock $\varepsilon_{t+1}$ is random and the best prediction is just its mean, zero (random walk with drift would have a constant term extra).

Regarding the last question of quantifying forecasting performance, you could take a look at established measures such as root mean squared error (RMSE), mean absolute error (MAE), mean absolute percentage error (MAPE), mean absolute scaled error (MASE) and the like. MASE will perhaps be the closest to your requirement of fitting in between zero and one. It will not necessarily be smaller than one, but the interpretation will be quite clear: MASE>1 will signal that the out-of-sample forecast does poorer than a naive forecast performs in sample.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, but I am a bit confused now what else if not a random walk are those kind of data series.

let's say I have the data c(1,1,0.9,1,1,1.1,1,1,1,1,1,0.9), than personally I would not predict the next value with 2, but probably with its mean value from the past. How is that kind of model called and how would it look like in ARIMA(x,x,x).

Comment: I would simply predict the next value as the mean of all previous values in this example. That would be 0.985. It would be ARIMA(0,0,0) with an intercept.

Comment: Alright, I would take the mean value too, because it looks obvious for me in this example. What I wanted to find out is, if there is a metric that quantifies this "obvious" in a single number.
So the best thing would be to use the MASE here, by calculating the error for each past value (0.985-1,...), etc. ?

Comment: You should start by specifying a loss function (RMSE is quite a typical choice, but it depends). Given a dataset and a model, calculate the particular value of the loss function. If you have a few models, you can compare their performance in terms of this loss function. Of course, try to avoid overfitting and data mining in the bad sense.

Comment: so in this example the RMSE would be the standard deviation sqrt((0.985-1)²+(0.985-1)²,...)?

Comment: We need one more step here. We have been fitting models in sample. Then RMSE can coincide with standard deviation because we are able to "predict" the mean perfectly. But in reality you will be forecasting out of sample and you will not know the mean. One way to account for this is splitting your sample into a training part and a test part. Estimate models on the training part, make out-of-sample predictions targeting the training part and assess model performance on the training part.

Comment: What still is a bit unclear to me is the interpretation of the MASE, which I tried to use now. An accuracy measure should show me how well my model can predict future data, like an accuracy metric show me for a classification model (in %).

But the accuracy measures I found to compare models between different time series like MASE don't provide that information. It always depends on the "naive" model. But sometimes the naive model can already predict future values well and therefore the found model won't have a significant lower error rate but it's still useful to predict future values.

Comment: The difference between regression and classification is quite stark here. In classification, you can simply calculate the percentage of correct classifications. There is no such thing in regression. So you can use either absolute measures such as RMSE or MAE or relative measures such as MAPE or MASE. Since the mistake in forecasting can be arbitrarily large, it would be difficult to bound an error measure between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes it's quite different to classification I see. I think MAPE is the closest thing to the accuracy metric in classification tasks? It sounds suitable for my needs because it's independent from a "naive" model and I can use it to compare different time series. So I can use it to tell how "predictable" my data is, which is not possible with MAPE I think.

Comment: You must have meant "MASE" instad of "MAPE" in the last line? I would not say that MAPE is especially close to the percentage of correct classifications, but it will tell you how much % on average your prediction is off the true/realized value.

Comment: Yes I meant MASE in the last line. Sure it's different to classifications, because the classes are nominal and there is no way to calculate a difference to the actual value. But I can use it similar and is probably the closest thing to "how well the model can predict my data in a percentage".

Comment: It's up to you to choose what is the most useful accuracy measure. Just be aware of the true meaning of each measure. In classification, there are natural boundaries; you classify some percentage of the cases correctly and the rest incorrectly. In regression, there is no boundary how wrong your forecast can be. You can be off by 1%, 100% or even 1000% (with a bad enough model).